# Как заменить определенную строку на <input> после нажатия на кнопку c помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть html для моего проекта. Я не разбираюсь в JS и верстке, но проект требует наличие хоть какого-либо визуала. Мне нужно, что бы при нажатии на кнопку `изменить имя` поле `name` поменялось на ввод `<input type ="text">`, а сама кнопка поменялась на кнопку `сохранить`, которая после нажатия отправляет мне данные через POST и меняется обратно на `изменить`. Аналогично и с `birthday`. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

```
<div class="name" id="name">
    Aleksey
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="тут вызов функции">
    Изменить имя
</button>

<div class ="birthday" id="birthday">
    22.02.1999
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="тут вызов функции">
    Изменить дату
</button>

<script>
// тут что то надо написать
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button[type=button]').forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const fieldset = event.target.closest('fieldset');
    fieldset
      .querySelector('button[type="submit"]')
      .classList
      .remove('hidden');
    fieldset.querySelector('input').disabled = false;
    event.target.classList.add('hidden');    
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
}

input[disabled] {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="http://foo.com">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Aleksey" disabled>
    <button type="button">Изменить имя</button>
    <button type="submit" class="hidden">Сохранить</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="date" name="birthday" value="22.02.1999" disabled>
    <button type="button">Изменить дату</button>
    <button type="submit" class="hidden">Сохранить</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Это то что нужно, спасибо большое !